# VS2012 Service based database - Not getting Add new table option

Tags: c#, sql-server, visual-studio-2012

I'm not getting option to add new table when I used Service base database in VS2012.
I know its basic question but missing something here...
how can I add new table or new stored procedures to this database.
Please Advise.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to install SQL Data Tools, you can get it from [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/hh297027).